# iis access error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6

I`m using IIS6.0.  How can I correct the following error:
 I am having the error:

> Access to the path 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\global.asax' is denied. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
>   path 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\global.asax' is denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
>   the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add
>   the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and
>   check the boxes for the desired access.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\global.asax' is denied.]
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   +9726046    System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share,
>   Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs,
>   String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath) +1142
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share) +83
>   System.Web.Hosting.MapPathBasedVirtualFile.Open() +75
>   System.Web.Hosting.VirtualPathProvider.OpenFile(String virtualPath)
>   +31    System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath) +133
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseInternal() +86
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse() +160
>   System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
>   +110    System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider
>   buildProvider) +65
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
>   +218    System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() +40    System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean
>   isPrecompiledApp) +8973974
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() +50
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +265
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Access to the path
>   'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\global.asax' is denied.]
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException()
>   +62    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() +421
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallAppInitializeMethod() +31
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +605
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Access to the path
>   'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\global.asax' is denied.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +8946484 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +97
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
>   +258
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

Comment: Have you performed what it suggests in the error text?

Comment: Yeah, this is actually one of the most descriptive error messages detailing how to overcome the security issue.  Likely due to NTFS ACLs being improperly (or not) set.

Comment: Does IUSR_MACHINENAME have access? Else just try for the sake of getting it working give access to everyone/anonymous? ... seems like the best geuss.

Comment: @Jared how do I set the NTFS ACLs? Sorry for the question, but doing that first time on windows server 2003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command propmt you could try

```
cacls 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\ /E /G "Everyone":F
```

You can also do it the UI way ... but you might allready know how to do that. But you better use the user that actually runs the IIS server.

Comment: I am doing that for the first time on windows server 2003.  I haven`t done what it suggests in the error. Could you please tell me the steps to do it so that I can grant permission accordingly.  Thanks

Comment: I don`t know how to do it using the UI way

Comment: Then use the command line as described above. Using the UI should be fairly easy to use and you should be able to bing/google that. but basically: Right click on the folder, Properties, Secirity and then add the missing permissions.